# Dynamic binary from file

Tags: c++, dynamic, binary, assembly

This is a little bit of weird problem here.

Say I have a C++ code, running on a specific platform. The only purpose of this code is to run files containing binary, NATIVE to that platform.

Now - my question is - HOW would I get the data from these files (could even be by bits, like 1024 bits a cycle) to the memory of machine running my code so that this data would be in the execution part?

In other words, can I get the data to somewhere where I can point the instruction pointer?

If yes, how?

I don't mind if I have to use assembler for this - just so it would work.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I wasn't specific enough.

Basically - the file data I want to load is in no format like .exe, Mach-O executable or ELF. It is just raw binary data (with some *custom* headers which my code removes). This binary data is machine code, specific and suited for the processor running on the current machine.

Technically this means I want to go around normal OS executors and load the binary directly. I could interpret it but that would be around 3x slower at best.

I would not mind at all if I need to run the data in another child process - but again, I can not use normal process openers, because the data is not in any format that the OS could run automatically (again - like .exe, Mach-O, ELF).

Comment: if by run you mean execute another binary, what's wrong with `fork()` and `system()`?

Comment: You don't say anything about your target, and this is very target dependant.

Comment: Where in the world are you getting binary chunks to execute, devoid of language or platform?

Comment: I said it is a "binary chunk" that is native to the said machine / processor / architecture. Something like when you compile without linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just read file to memory, mark this memory as executable (it's platform-specific, for example `VirtualProtect()` for Windows), and call it as function: `((void(*)())ptr)();`

Of course code in file should be [position-independent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code).

Comment: I would expect that this works, except that you'll need to setup the return from this code-block.  Presumably your binary chunks that you're running themselves do not have any stack setup/tear-down conventions - just expecting a jump-into their code.  So the above, plus manually adding the return from-function code appropriate for the current platform may well be enough.

Comment: To expand on Mordachai’s comment:  If the executable bits in the loaded file “look like” C functions, then Abyx’s suggestion will work; `dlsym` _et al._ work that way.  If it’s “raw” chunks “just expecting a jump into their code”, though, you might be able to construct a custom `jmp_buf` and use C’s `longjmp()`.

Comment: @Mordachai, JCSalomon - yes I understand that - the binary chunks are ready for this kind of loading, and are not just pulled out of context. Also - Abyx - could you be more specific with the execution marking, for major platforms? It seems that these OS specific funtions are what I really need.

Answer (score 0):

How generic does your solution need to be?

The OS loader usually knows how to handle specific file formats and how to load them into memory. You can usually use the OS loader and call the entry point, but for that you need to know what is the entry point and for that you need to understand the file format anyway. I can't think of a portable solution for that.

If you'll explain more about what you want to do maybe it will be possible to supply a solution.